# How to do dependency injection for objects created with TypeListener in Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Assuming such module configure method:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindListener(Matchers.any(), new TranslationKeyListener());
    }

    class TranslationKeyListener implements TypeListener {
        public <T> void hear(TypeLiteral<T> typeLiteral, TypeEncounter<T> typeEncounter) {
            Class<?> clazz = typeLiteral.getRawType();

            while (clazz != null) {
                for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                    Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
                    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(TranslationKey.class) &&
                            (fieldType == Translation.class)) {
                        TranslationKey key = field.getAnnotation(TranslationKey.class);

                        String theKey = key.value();
                        typeEncounter.register(new TranslationInjector<T>(field, theKey));
                    }
                }
                clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
            }
        }
    }

    class TranslationInjector<T> implements MembersInjector<T> {
        private final Field field;
        private final TranslationImpl translation;

        TranslationInjector(Field field, String key) {
            this.field = field;
            this.translation = new TranslationImpl(key, true);
            field.setAccessible(true);
        }

        @SneakyThrows
        public void injectMembers(T t) {
            field.set(t, translation);
        }
   }
```

and usage in another class like

```java
@TranslationKey("someKey")
private Translation translation; // implemented by TranslationImpl
```

how can I make sure that dependcies - class fields - using @Inject inside TranslationImpl will be injected as well?
in the same way that `requestInjection(this)` works within a module, but this is not supported when called outside configure()...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found the trick - Guice is rejecting any other attempts to use `MembersInjector` if it's not used *exactly*  this way.
The resulting errors of all other attempts has varied from "recursive load", "can't use before Injector is created" and others...
Attempting to call `getMembersInjector` before creating TranslationImpl also triggers "recursive load" error for a reason I don't yet understand, but moving it past that makes it work.

```java
    class TranslationKeyListener implements TypeListener {
        public <T> void hear(TypeLiteral<T> typeLiteral, TypeEncounter<T> typeEncounter) {
            Class<?> clazz = typeLiteral.getRawType();

            while (clazz != null) {
                for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                    Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
                    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(TranslationKey.class) &&
                            (fieldType == Translation.class)) {
                        TranslationKey key = field.getAnnotation(TranslationKey.class);

                        String theKey = key.value()
                        TranslationImpl impl = new TranslationImpl(theKey, true);
                        MembersInjector injector =
                                typeEncounter.getMembersInjector(TranslationImpl.class);

                        typeEncounter.register(new TranslationInjector(field, impl));
                        typeEncounter.register(new MembersInjector<T>() {
                            @Override
                            public void injectMembers(T instance) {
                                injector.injectMembers(impl);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
            }
        }
    }
```